# SQL Server View Incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, view, pivot-table

i have the following DB:

[image: My DB]

I want to create view that give this information in a row:

```
document_id    Creator    Manager    Special    Archive
```

(Creator,Manager,Special,Archive)  are AuthorityName values

So fisrt i created a view:

```
SELECT     dbo.DocumentAuthorities.DocumentId, dbo.DocumentAuthorities.AuthorityId,   dbo.Authorities.AuthorityName, dbo.Authorities.AuthorityLevel
FROM         dbo.DocumentAuthorities CROSS JOIN
                          dbo.Authorities
```

then i tried this:

```
 SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT Documents.Id, AuthorityName.AuthorityId, AuthorityName.AuthorityName
    FROM AuthorityName CROSS JOIN Documents
     ) src 
     PIVOT
     ( 
        max(dbo.AuthorityName.AuthorityName) 
        FOR AuthorityName 
        IN ([Creator],[Director],[Special],[Archive])
      )
```

but i get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

You have to give an alias name for your pivot table

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT Documents.Id, AuthorityName.AuthorityId, AuthorityName.AuthorityName
FROM AuthorityName CROSS JOIN Documents
 ) src 
 PIVOT
 ( 
    max(dbo.AuthorityName.AuthorityName) 
    FOR AuthorityName 
    IN ([Creator],[Director],[Special],[Archive])
  ) P -- < HERE
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, but now i think the other view is not correct.